# How can we use $1, $2 and vise versa?

Tags: php, variables, code-snippets

Actually I want to get values of array in different variables, so I made this code:

```
$count = count( $t );
$count = $count - 1;//count starts with 1 and array starts with 0

for ($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++) { 
    $$i = $t[$i];//$0 = something; $2 = something; vise versa
}
// $i = 1;
// $i++;
// $$i = $2;
var_dump($1,$2,$3);
```

I can create this variables but cannot access them as $1 is not recognized as variables.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\stackoverflow\test.php on line 56

I want to use $0, $1, $2, etc.

Comment: First rule of programming :- Variable name must starts with alphabets or underscore...

Comment: According to naming convention PHP variable can not start with numbers

Comment: then how we turn array into different variables (name)

Comment: You don't. Why would you? Flooding your scope with random variable names has never done anyone any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you are trying to achieve, but it can be done like this:

```
$number = 1;
$$number = 'OK';

echo ${1};
```

Will output:

```
OK
```

Comment: perfect work dude! that is what i want. Waiting for accept

Answer (score 1):

Variable names can't start with numbers in PHP:

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Instead of using numbered variables, you should work directly with your `$t` array instead.